# SVGs as ReactComponents, double clicking highlights next text

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, google-chrome

I use a number of SVGs through-out my react app, and I import them as ReactComponents:

```
import { ReactComponent as InfoIcon } from "../../resources/svg/icons/basic/info-icon.svg";
```

then I'll use it in my component like so:

```
<div className="icon-container" ref={seekingLRef}>
    <SeekingLeft className="icon" />
</div>
```

My problem is, that whenever I double click on any SVG in the app, it highlights text on the next closest element in the html tree that has text.  Typically that is a sibling, but if there are no sibling elements that have text, it just goes to the parent's sibling, etc.

I attempted to preventDefault and stopPropgation on the onClick event handlers, but this didn't have any impact on the text highlighting.

I also noticed this happens on most sites actually where an image isn't interactable, and it seems to be a chrome specific functionality (it does not occur on firefox). Is there a way to prevent this behavior other than using css user-select: none?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share your implemented code in JSFiddle or Stackblitz to exactly get an idea of the issue. Moreover, I tried to implement it myself and it didn't seem to occur in my case (I am using Chrome).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the svg to have a css property of user-select: none; it shouldn't highlight other items on double clicking.

`user-select: none;`